# C# ffmpeg unable to load dll avcodec

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, avcodec

I downloaded project to controlling AR Drone from this site:

```
https://github.com/Ruslan-B/AR.Drone
```

This project is old. Then I downloaded ffmpeg.autogen library from this site

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-autogen/?source=typ_redirect
```

This is old version of ffmpeg because of old version AR.Drone. I has to be .NET Framework 4.0 version.

Project has compiled, but when I run application I got an error:

```
"Unable to load DLL 'avcodec': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"
```

The error occurs in this line:

```
FFmpegInvoke.avcodec_register_all();
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a component.  Perhaps try downloading the component ffmpeg component https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html.... I'd also consider posting this to the issues page https://github.com/Ruslan-B/AR.Drone/issues

Comment: I've downloaded ffmpeg, but the problem is rather that I don't have avcodec.dll registered on my machine and I don't know from where I can download it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice to clone the project including submodules.
Here is the quote from README.md:

```
git clone http://github.com/Ruslan-B/AR.Drone.git   
cd AR.Drone   
git submodule update --init
```

It supposed download not only source code but compatible ffmpeg binaries as well.

As a next step you need to build AR.Drone solution with VS2012+ it going to build all dependencies for you and then you will be able to start AR.Drone.WinApp project. It will auto pickup the ffmpeg binaries by convention.